# How to manipulate string parts?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, string-manipulation

Let's consider I have following string:

```
"{a-> POR, b-> D610, c-> 0, d-> \"300/7\", e -> \"1/400\"}"
```

How can I run over and update anything that is between `" "` to be an expression. So that having following result:

```
   {a-> POR, b-> D610, c-> 0, d-> ToExpression["300/7"], e -> ToExpression["1/400"]}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The quotes stay strangely. The fragment `"5/2"" `does not seem to be correct.

Comment: "5/2"" this is correct. I just need to replace everything that is in quotes to expression.

Comment: No, please see the update

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ToExpression[
  "{a-> POR, b-> D610, c-> 0, d-> \"300/7\", e -> \"1/400\"}"
  ] /. s_String :> Defer @ ToExpression[s]
```

> ```
> {a -> POR, b -> D610, c -> 0, d -> ToExpression["300/7"], 
>  e -> ToExpression["1/400"]}
> ```

---

response to comment:

```
ToExpression[
  "{a-> POR, b-> D610, c-> 0, d-> \"300/7\", e -> \"1/400\"}"
] /. (lhs : Except[d] -> rhs_String) :> (lhs -> Defer @ ToExpression[rhs])
```

> ```
> {a -> POR, b -> D610, c -> 0, d -> "300/7", 
>  e -> ToExpression["1/400"]}
> ```

Comment: Can you please add a check here? e.g. to check if the left of the rules is "d", skip it?

Comment: @SuTron like in the edit?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Sorry for being nasty :) but is it possible to have in the output already evaluated ToExpression["300/7"] view, instead of "ToExpression["300/7"]"?

Comment: @SuTron yes, skip `Defer, no problem :)

Comment: That works for ToExpression, but for Quantity it doesn't, e.g. Quantity["1/2 s"]

Comment: Sorry, my bad, made a typo.

Comment: I have noticed that it works in case of ToExpression[], but doesn't in case of ToExpression[..., StandardForm, HoldForm ], any idea?